# Ps3 superslim no display even after resetting display settings

Tags: ps3

I have a ps3 superslim (CECH-4008C) and a few days ago i turned it on to find that there were some green and red dots on the left side of the screen and my ps3 froze on the boot screen (trumpet sound and wave moving). Since then, i've tried resetting my display settings, changing HDMI ports, using an AV cable, connecting ps3 to different TV's, doesn't even boot into recovery mode, But no luck. Help me please. it turns on showing the green light but the tv shows no signal after all ive tried. it has to be turned off forcefully as it doesn't turn off in a single press of the Power button.

Answer (score 0):

The issue must be due to a dead hard drive inside your console.
Consider doing the following things:

1) Confirm if the Output (tv etc) is working properly
2) remove the HDD and try to connect it using an adapter to your PC & check if it is recognized by your PC.
3) Please confirm, when was the last time you were able to successfully load your console & whether you had shut down properly?